# RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, webrtc

I have a project that is using WebRTC to establish a connection between peers and send a file. I'm working off of old code, but it currently works in Chrome. I'm having trouble getting it to work in Firefox and can't tell what the issue is.

Here is my code:

```
this.connection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
...
const desc = await this.connection.createOffer();
this.localConnection.setLocalDescription(desc);
console.log('local description', this.localConnection.localDescription);
```

For the value of `this.localConnection.localDescription`:

- Chrome prints `RTCSessionDescription {type: "offer", sdp: ...}`
- Firefox prints `null`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the [webrtc-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter) package?

Comment: I am not, but according to https://developer.mozilla.org/, `RTCPeerConnection`, `createOffer`, and `setLocalDescription` are all fully supported by both Chrome and Firefox. So I feel like I shouldn't need a compatibility adapter?

Comment: I think the problem is around the setLocalDescription method, I'd try it with await. `await this.localConnection.setLocalDescription(desc);`

Comment: Eyyy, that worked. Good catch, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, I'll make it as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is around the `setLocalDescription` method, it may not set immediately in firefox, I'd try it with await:

```
await this.localConnection.setLocalDescription(desc);
console.log('local description', this.localConnection.localDescription);
```